# Insert <br> tag to the second textbox JS

Tags: javascript

I'm building a simple text editor and I start with basics - as user press enter and start a new line a want to insert **br** to the the second textbox. The second textbox is meant to send ready formatted text to the database. As of now I managed to copy data from first to second textbox as user typing. Hence, I want to disable viewing **br** in the first textbox. Is there a way not to display **br** in the first textbox but technically have it. Thank you in advance!

DEMO: https://jsfiddle.net/mxr7hz3p/

Textboxes:

```
 <textarea type="text" id="first"></textarea>
 <textarea type="text" id="second"></textarea>
```

JS:

```
$(function (){
    $('#first').keyup(function (e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13){
            var curr = getCaret(this);
            var val = $(this).val();
            var end = val.length;
                
            $(this).val( val.substr(0, curr) + '<br>' + val.substr(curr, end));
    }})
});

    function getCaret(el) { 
       if (el.selectionStart) { 
          return el.selectionStart; 
       }
       else if (document.selection) { 
            el.focus(); 

            var r = document.selection.createRange(); 
                if (r == null) { 
                return 0; 
            } 

            var re = el.createTextRange(), 
            rc = re.duplicate(); 
            re.moveToBookmark(r.getBookmark()); 
            rc.setEndPoint('EndToStart', re); 

            return rc.text.length; 
         }  
         return 0; 
     }
```

```
$('#first').keyup(function(){
    $('#second').val(this.value);
});
```

Comment: You want a [`contenteditable`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Editable_content)?

Comment: What I would do is just have a single text box and then when sending to server replace all new line characters with `<br />` at that point. It would be much simpler.

You could also just replace new line characters with `<br />` and insert into 2nd text box on keyup.

Comment: Gareth, do you mean catch \n and then format it to <br>. How can I go about it?

Comment: I put it as a separate answer, but you can just do a string replace on a keyup event of the first textarea then copy it into the 2nd textarea

Comment: It never crossed my mind, really. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simplify the JS in the fiddle to do this

```
$('#first').keyup(function(){
  var val = $(this).val();

  val = val.replace(/\n/g, '<br />')

  $('#second').val(val);
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/t3vzgnp7/2/